# How can double-clicking be disabled for just one portion of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with row selection enabled. Before today, my desired functionality was for double-clicking on any given row to open up a new window. And before today, that worked just fine.

I've just added a column of `JCheckBox`es to the table. Selecting and deselecting individual checkboxes in the new column works fine, in general. However, if I select a checkbox and quickly deselect it, the table interprets my actions as a double-click on the checkbox's row, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to disable the double-clicking behavior for just the checkboxes, but keeping row selection enabled otherwise? If not, how about disabling the behavior for just one column of a table? If so, how?

Comment: if it's an option: not open the window at all if the cell underneath is editable and has a cellEditor with startOnSingleClick

Comment: @kleopatra, hm, I'm not familiar with `CellEditor`. Time to do some Googling. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If not, how about disabling the behavior for just one column of a table?

Use the table.columnAtPoint(...) method to ignore double clicks on the columm with the checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

In the `MouseListener` you could check the state of the checkbox of the selected row for each click and if the second click's state doesn't match the first click's state then don't open a new window.

Comment: This looks like a good workaround for my specific case. Any idea about the more general case, though? Next time this comes up, it might be for a dropdown list or a button or some other non-checkbox component.

Comment: @LordTor, I think camickr's answer is better for the more general case.

Comment: Indeed, he posted that right after I commented. FWIW I've upvoted both of you. I think I'm going to end up implementing this, though.